# Нет звука при воспроизведении нот в C#

Tags: c#, аудио

Ребята, всем привет. При попытке исполнить программу воспроизведения нот в C# нет звука, хотя прога исполняется. Динамики в порядке, музыка играет. Длительность достаточная, 1000 мс

```
namespace _002_MusicScale {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.Beep(523 ,1000); // До
            Console.Beep(587, 1000); // Ре
            Console.Beep(659, 1000); // Ми
            Console.Beep(698, 1000); // Фа
            Console.Beep(784, 1000); // Соль
            Console.Beep(880, 1000); // Ля
            Console.Beep(988, 1000); // Си
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приложили бы код к программе что-ли

Comment: Стандартное учебное задание

Comment: у вопроса есть кнопка "править" - кинь код туда

Comment: На каком компьютере запускаете программу? Есть ли там динамик-пищалка? Не все компы (зависит от железа) воспроизводят `Beep` через звуковуху, если нет пищалки.

Comment: комп Dell Inspirion 15 7000 Gaming

Comment: Ещё раз: пищалка есть? Не важно название компа.

Comment: Да, пищалки просто не оказалось. Благодарствую)) попробовал включить и выключить через командную строку. Толку ноль.

Comment: Современные компы умеют пищать через звукаху, пищалки может и не быть, но звук может быть.